# If we change fragment before countdowntimer is finished, the application crashes in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As soon as the application opens, I use a 2-second countdown timer. After 2 second I visible linearlayout and invisible progressbar. The reason I use this is because I can pull all data through firebase and assign it to the corresponding text boxes. However, if I pass to another activity during the countdown timer, the program crashes.

```
object : CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                  linearLayout_profile.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                  progressBar_profile.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }.start()
```

```
2020-12-10 00:50:24.118 1742-1742/com.burakergun.emre E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.burakergun.emre, PID: 1742
    java.lang.NullPointerException: linearLayout_profile must not be null
        at com.burakergun.emre.Fragment.ProfileFragment$onViewCreated$3.onFinish(ProfileFragment.kt:66)
        at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2020-12-10 00:50:24.185 1742-1742/com.burakergun.emre I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1742 SIG: 9
```

I check the logcat and show the fatal error. The error says linearlayout_profile must be not null. How can linearlayout_profile be null. I dont understand that
part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linearlayout_profile` is null because you navigated to another activity and there is no reference to `linearlayout_profile` and hence null.

You need to add null check to prevent the crash.

Comment: I didn't think to check if it is null or not null. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when you passed to another activity you should destroy timer

```
   override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    timer?.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null

    private fun startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            val secondsUntilFinished: Long = ceil(millisUntilFinished.toDouble() / 1000).toLong()

            val string: String = getString(R.string.resend_code_after).replace("*", secondsUntilFinished.toString())
            binding.resendOTP.text = string
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            val string: String = getString(R.string.resend_code)
            binding.resendOTP.text = string
        }
    }.start()
}
```

then when you want to change fragment or activity use this code in onClick or Nav function to cancel countDown before change fragment or activity

```
countDownTimer!!.cancel()
```